# Type '{ class: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code

I am using vue, ts, vite with volar extension.

In Vs code, I get the error
`Type '{ class: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'. Property 'class' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'. Did you mean 'className'?ts(2322)`

when I do `<div class=""></div>` for the `class`

When I hover over the `div` I see
`(property) div: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>`

I don't know what's making vs code assume I am using react. The file type is `.vue`

I disabled eslint and still get the error. It works when I run the app but it's annoying to see that error in vscode.

Am I supposed to add some `d.ts` file?

Comment: What is the file type? Are you writing jsx?

Comment: @vatz88 no, it's `.vue`

Comment: @vatz88 i am using the script setup(https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html)

Comment: Use internal types then (`DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>`) or change your typing, because DOM elements really doesn't contains `class` property, maybe you mean `className` / `classList`?

Comment: Also you can extend type using `type extendedType =  DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement> & { class: string }`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Adding this fixed it. See here: https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar/discussions/592

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "types": [
      "vite/client", // if using vite
      // ...
    ]
  }
}
```

I think when I added storybook it added react types

Comment: It didn't solve my problem

Comment: I was experiencing this issue running yarn build with an out-of-the-box vite vue >2.7 template, and adding this to the tsconfig is what resolved it.  Odd that it's not included in the template initially.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I had to to add `<script>` tags:

```
<script> //your code </script>
```

Comment: This worked for me. The accepted answer didn't.

Answer (score 1):

1. As Abhi pointed out, explicitly set up the tsconfig `types` option, it can prevent TypeScript from including all types from `node_modules/@types` automatically.

```js
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
      "vite/client",
    ]
  }
}
```

2. If the problem persists, `@types/xxx` may include by some import statement. You need to find out which and exclude it. For example if you are using storybook and it uses a `import ... from '@storybook/vue3'` statement, you need to exclude all files that have a `'@storybook/vue3'` import statement.

```js
// tsconfig.json
{
  "exclude": ["**/*.stories.ts"]
}
```

Comment: In my case, this solution solved problem. There is an issue with Storybook. I updated Storybook. I guess as Storybook supports now Typescript it add some think related to React.

Answer (score -1):

i have the same problem,but i did not do anything,so i guess its the problem with vscode, i change the vscode plugin `Vue languages Features` to
previous version，then its works